# how to detect if user is on magento dashboard to view order data

Tags: magento2

I am working on integrating my custom app with magento2. I want to detect when user goes to dashboard(my recent orders and my orders section). I need to get the customer order collection and perform few actions which will give me current status of orders and depending upon that i need to make sure user sees the updated status in dashboard.

How can i detect whether user is on dashboard/my order page? is there any event which is triggered for which I can write observer?